# Why won't my UIActivityIndicatorView stop animating?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to manage the activity indicator from my App Delegate, that way any of my views can put the indicator up.  So, I am adding it as a subview to 'window' and start/stop as follows:

```
- (void)didStartActivity
{
    if( activityIndicator == nil ) {
        activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
        activityIndicator.center = window.center;
        activityIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 6.0, 6.0);
    }
    NSLog(@"%s: starting the activityIndicator", __FUNCTION__);
    [window addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

I see the log messages, so I know the code is being invoked.  The indicator is at the center and 6x the default size.  However, the stopAnimating isn't stopping.  The only thing I can conclude is that it needs to run in the present view controller.

```
- (void)didStopActivity
{
    NSLog(@"%s: stopping the activityIndicator", __FUNCTION__);
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: is didStopActivity getting called? Does the -removeFromSuperview work?

Comment: yes .. the log shows the call to didStopActivity and I only called the removeFromSuperview as overkill.  I expected the stopAnimating to stop and the default setting of 'hideWhenStopped' to hide, but neither is happening.  I will be experimenting with it in the VC rather than the appDelegate and see if that makes a difference.  In other words, as a subview of the VC's view versus as a subview of window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I did my experiment and sure enough, it worked flawlessly when I added the activity indicator as a subview of viewcontroller's view.  However, when I then used that new simpleton project to try it as a subview to window it also worked.  Obviously a bug in my code and it needs more inspection.

I will award both Eimantas with the answer as the debug notion was helpful in my solution.

Answer (score 8):

Are you trying to do this from a background thread? An easy and definitive test would be to add:

```
NSLog(@"thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
```

Comment: No it was my subviewing (see below).  But this is a good debug tip.

Answer (score 0):

check if your `activityIndicator` isn't `nil`:

```
NSLog(@"activityIndicator: %@", activityIndicator);
```

Comment: No, its non-nil as indicated by the log.  Good idea -- do you think it has anything to do with it being created and managed in the app delegate?



2010-01-30 13:07:46.073 MyApp[35463:4803] -[MyAppDelegate didStopActivity]: stopping the activityIndicator <UIActivityIndicatorView: 0x3b26e90; frame = (49 129; 222 222); transform = [6, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]; animations = { contents=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x3b28750>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x3b271a0>>

Answer (score 0):

if your log is nil then do this:

in ".h" declare :

```
__strong UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator
```

the __strong avoid ARC and then you can remove and stop the activityIndicator.

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding it to the superview more than one time it will not work.

Try putting

```
[superView addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

into the

```
if( activityIndicator == nil ) {
```

condition