# Must I call UIActivityIndicatorView.stopAnimating before UIView.removeFromSuperview?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiactivityindicatorview

Do I need (or is it good practice) to call `stopAnimating()` before I remove a `UIActivityIndicatorView` from its superview? If so, why? If not, why not?

Related:

- [UIActivityIndicatorView proper usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622301/uiactivityindicatorview-proper-usage)
- [Why won't my UIActivityIndicatorView stop animating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168902/why-wont-my-uiactivityindicatorview-stop-animating)

Example:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if refreshing {
        if tableView.backgroundView == nil {
            let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
            activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
            tableView.backgroundView = activityIndicatorView
        }
        return 0
    }
    // Should I stop animating the activityIndicatorView here?
    tableView.backgroundView = nil
    return 2
}
```